# ImportError: cannot import name HTMLCalendar

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ubuntu, django-models

```
File "managers.py", line 2, in <module> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py", line 7, in <module> from django.db import models 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py", line 6, in <module> from django.db.models.query import Q, QuerySet, Prefetch # NOQA 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 16, in <module> from django.db.models import sql 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/__init__.py", line 2, in <module> from django.db.models.sql.subqueries import * # NOQA 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 9, in <module> from django.db.models.sql.query import Query 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 17, in <module> from django.db.models.aggregates import Count 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/aggregates.py", line 5, in <module> from django.db.models.expressions import Func, Star File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 7, in <module> from django.db.models import fields 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 19, in <module> from django import forms 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/__init__.py", line 6, in <module> from django.forms.fields import * # NOQA 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 21, in <module> from django.forms.utils import from_current_timezone, to_current_timezone 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/utils.py", line 12, in <module> from django.utils.html import escape, format_html, format_html_join, html_safe 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/html.py", line 13, in <module> from django.utils.http import RFC3986_GENDELIMS, RFC3986_SUBDELIMS 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/http.py", line 4, in <module> import calendar 
File "/home/homa/Desktop/zinnia/calendar.py", line 4, in <module> from calendar import HTMLCalendar ImportError: cannot import name HTMLCalendar
```

Below is the import:

```
from calendar import HTMLCalendar

class Calendar(HTMLCalendar):
    """
    Extension of the HTMLCalendar.
    """
```

Comment: Where `HTMLCalendar` is defined?

Comment: I understand what problem you are facing, but in general you should provide as much information as possible. Can you remove the code that is not immediately relevant to your question? (i.e. the huge error message).

Comment: Type in terminal "pip freeze" and check there is module is available or not

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the HTMLcalendar.py is  not located in python's search path.
You can check the path with

```
import sys
sys.path
```

If the directory of HTMLcalendar.py is not in the python path you can add it in the script with

```
sys.path.append('path')
```

Note: the path will revert to normal after you finish with the script. If you want to make it permanent you will have to edit the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: To use these commands you simply need to be in a python shell and copy-paste. In general, can you explain your needs with more words? I have difficulties understanding where you get stuck.